# Unable to upload images to IPFS using ipfs-http-client

Tags: javascript, react, ipfs

I am having an issue with uploading images to IPFS after having switched to `ipfs-http-client` from `ipfs-api`. This is what my page code is like at the moment:

```
import ipfs from "../utils/ipfs";

export default function NewReview() {

    const [ipfsHash, setIpfsHash] = useState("");
    const [buffer, setBuffer] = useState(null);
    const [isFile, setFile] = useState(null);

    function getHash() {
        ipfs.files.add(Buffer.from(buffer), (error, result) => {
            if (error) {
                console.error(error)
                return
            }
            setIpfsHash(result[0].hash);
    });
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (buffer) {
            getHash()
        }
    });

    const captureFile = (event) => {
        if (event.target.files[0]) {
            event.preventDefault();
            setFile(URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]));
        
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(event.target.files[0])
            reader.addEventListener("load", () => {
                    setBuffer(reader.result)
            })
        }
    }

// skipping a bit to where the image is uploaded

<div>
    <img src={isFile} alt="" style={{ maxWidth: '400px' }} />
    <input type="file" onChange={captureFile} />
</div>

// I don't think the rest is relevant
```

The images are meant to be saved to the blockchain via a smart contract function and should be displayed on another page like this:

```
// other code
<li className="list-group-item">
    <img src={ `https://ipfs.io/ipfs/${review.ipfsHash}` } alt="" />
</li>
```

This is what `ipfs.js` looks like:

```
const { create } = require('ipfs-http-client');
const ipfs = create({host: 'ipfs.infura.io', port: 5001, protocol: 'https'});

export default ipfs;
```

When I was using `ipfs-api` the above code used to work. However with `ipfs-http-client` I can't used `ipfs.files.add` as I get a `TypeError: default.files.add is not a function` error.

I have tried replacing `ipfs.files.add` with just `ipfs.add` but that doesn't work, even if I put the buffer in a JavaScript object as the documentation for `ipfs.add` suggests I do. I don't even seem to get any error messages when I look at the console, it just doesn't seem to work and the `ipfsHash` is just an empty string (like the original state).

I'd really appreciate your thoughts and suggestions! Without even getting any errors in the console I'm not sure what the error is and how I can get `ipfs-http-client` to save an image file to IPFS like my code used to to successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem!

With `ipfs-http-client`, you need to use `ipfs.add` as part of an `async/await` function in order for `ipfs.add` to actually execute, it seems. Without it being in an `async/await` function, it didn't do anything at all when `getHash()` ran.

This is how I changed `getHash()`:

```
async function getHash() {
    
    try {
        const uploadResult = await ipfs.add(Buffer.from(buffer))
        setIpfsHash(uploadResult.path)
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e)
        toast.error(e.message)
        return
    }
}
```